# Issue related to IQueryable method (Cannot implicitly cast type 'long?' to 'long'

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, iqueryable

I have a IQueryable method as below:

```
public IQueryable<vmTest> TestMethod(long ID)
{
    return from m in db.table1
           join n in db.table2
           on m.table1_ID equals n.table1_ID into tabC
           from c in tabC
           join o in db.table3
           on m.table3_ID equals o.table3_ID
           where m.table1_ID.Equals(ID)
           select new vmTest{ field1 = m.xxx };
}
```

from the code above, **m.xxx** is a long type and in the **vmTest** there is a **public long field1**. There is error with **m.xxx** which saying **Cannot implicitly convert type 'long?' to 'long'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**.May I know what's wrong?

**Additional information:**
If i cast **(long)** in front of **m.xxx**, error will be dissapear but another problem occur when this query returning no value as it's wrong to cast **long** to **null**

Comment: As the error says: One is `long`, the other `long?` which is `Nullable<long>`. Which one is which is impossible to say from the code you have given.

Comment: Are you sure none of these two are nullable?

Comment: Actually I think we can say with certainty that `m.xxx` must be `long?` and `vmTest.field1` is `long`, because if it were the other way around it would work (`long` is implicitly convertible to `long?`).

Comment: in my **vmTest** class there isn't any field with nullable field

Comment: Alright my bad, I'm too new to MVC or even C#and hence never know that there is this a **long?** type which is different from **long**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several solutions:

- You can change vmTest class definition and replace field1 type from long to long?
- You can change your table in database and transforms xxx from NULL to NOT NULL then xxx will become a long
- You can use a condition in your query like

  ```
  new vmTest { field1 = m.xxx.HasValue ? m.xxx.Value : 0 }
  ```

More information on Nullables [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure of the types you want to use, you could try this:

```
public IQueryable<vmTest> TestMethod(long ID)
{
    return from m in db.table1
           join n in db.table2
           on m.table1_ID equals n.table1_ID into tabC
           from c in tabC
           join o in db.table3
           on m.table3_ID equals o.table3_ID
           where m.table1_ID.Equals(ID)
           select new vmTest
               { 
                    field1 = m.xxx.HasValue 
                        ? m.xxx.Value
                        : default(long) /*or something else, or an exception maybe... according to your expectation in this case*/ };
}
```